# ng-repeat-start giving only index '0' inside ng-change of an array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here i'm trying to pass businessJet object in **ng-change="info.onRampFeeApplicableChanged(businessJet)"** for toggle button inside ng-repeat-start. But it always gives object of first index even if you change toggle button of other index values. Where as it works fine for the  **"ng-click="info.onToggleAircarftMoreDetails(businessJet)"** inside the first td element.

Am i doing anything wrong? I couldn't figure out.

```
<div ng-repeat="aircraftType in info.fboRampFee">

    <table>
       <tbody>
          <tr class="row" ng-repeat-start="businessJet in aircraftType.businessJets track by $index">
             <td ng-click="info.onToggleAircarftMoreDetails(businessJet)"></td>
             <td>
             <span class="onoffswitch">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="businessJet-switch-{{$parent.$index}}" 
                      class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="businessJet-switch-{{$parent.$index}}" 
                      ng-model="businessJet.IsApplicable"
                   ng-change="info.onRampFeeApplicableChanged(businessJet)">
                     <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="businessJet-switch-{{$parent.$index}}">
                          <span class="onoffswitch-inner"
                                data-swchon-text="YES"
                                  data-swchoff-text="NO"></span>
                                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                     </label>
             </span>
           </td>
          </tr>

         <tr ng-repeat-end>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
       </tbody
    </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just remove ng-repeat-start and put ng-repeat
>   and remove ng-repeat-end from tr tag. Might be it will work fine

Comment: No it won't work either. I'm using ng-repeat-start ng-repeat-end to repeat / end values for multiple DOM elements. It won't work if i use single ng-repeat for everything. I'm surprised that it works for ng-click where as it isn't working for ng-change

Comment: one minute i'll give u solution

Comment: Dude, it's an input tag of type checkbox. Not a select option.

Comment: I think you can use ng-change in selection menu i didn't use ng-change in checkbox, ng-click is better option if it will work

Answer (score 0):

It should be only **id="businessJet-switch-{$index}}"** instead of **"id="businessJet-switch-{{$parent.$index}}"** as i had to take the index of the child array. It worked.